# CoreData & TimeMachine

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I'm developing a CoreData non-document-based app. The SQLite store size is regularly of order ~60MB, and it's cumbersome that Time Machine backs up the entire database once per hour. Is there a way to make Time Machine back up only the changes?

I'm thinking of abusing the [CoreData external records API for spotlight](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpotlightCoreData/Articles/recordLevel.html)
and let the machine back up only those external records. What do you think? The documentation says that the external records can only be in ~/Library/Caches/ or ~/Library/CoreData/; the former is automatically excluded from the backed up, and I'm not sure about the latter. I'm not sure how external records work with the CoreData versioning, either.

Comment: Maybe your choice of words wasn't perfect, but when you say "abusing the external records API" it immediately makes me think you're going to be doing the wrong thing, simply because of the fact you're calling it "abusing". If you're abusing something... then.. don't?

Comment: Well, yes and no... CoreData external records API automatically generates individual files for each entries in the CoreData store so that Spotlight can index it. Time Machine can then back them up in principle. So yes, it's not what Apple expected us to use the API for, but no, it wouldn't be "morally wrong"...

Comment: Given the fact that the structure of those records is private and subject to change, basing your application's documents on this feature out of laziness would be a very stupid decision--assuming it would work at all.

Comment: Well, the structure of the external records is as private as the detailed mapping to SQLite store from the CoreData abstraction. But there are two public APIs obtaining info out of external records. See elementsDerivedFromExternalRecordURL: and importStoreWithIdentifier:fromExternalRecordsDirectory:toURL:options:withType:error: in  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html
So yes, I'm stupid, but it should work, I guess.

Comment: Then do it and stop asking for approval.

Comment: Yes I'm doing that. I just want to know if somebody has tried the same thing and found any catch along the way and/or if somebody has found  alternative ways to achieve the same goal, etc. Any input is welcome!

Comment: +1 for caring about details like this.

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine backs up files, not individual database records.

Comment: I know. So I need to generate individual files for the CoreData entries. And the CoreData external records API is one way to achieve it with a few lines of code. I was wondering if anybody has (ab)used that API to improve backup performance.